# XAML DataTrigger binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

I try to apply datatrigger with binding like that

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="293"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                //...somes trigger...
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Path=isMaxOnglets}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The `<Setter Property="Width" Value="293"/>` is always applied and not the dataTrigger, 
I have this

```
mainModel.isMaxOnglets = true;
```

and this

```
bool _isMaxOnglets;
    public bool isMaxOnglets
    {
        get
        {
            return _isMaxOnglets;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isMaxOnglets != value)
                {
                    _isMaxOnglets = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("isMaxOnglets");
                }
            }
        }
```

Problem : The datatrigger is never applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Ancestor Binding`.

```
<Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=DataContext.isMaxOnglets}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

If `mainModel` is `DataContext` of `TabControl`.

Comment: I like elementName for binding to props in the page/window as it looks cleaner, but yes either way it looks like a error in targeting the prop

Comment: @Wobbles I think that elementName gives a tight coupling in XMAL. we should avoid this wherever possible. As a style with ancestor binding will be more reusable compare to elementName binding.

Comment: Oh yes ! thx you @Kylo Ren this is THE solution to my problem.... you saved my day ! thx you very much ! :D

Comment: @JuseNNN your welcome. It's one of the very common problem WPF programmer encounter with. :)